# Censor certain words and images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My question is how can i censor bad language and nudity images on my application, is there some sort of a framework that can filter the content that is introduced by the user? what are you, IOS experts, using at this moment to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your question: 1) Censoring text, 2) Censoring images.

In the case of text, you could store a dictionary and match user input to words that you want to censor.  However how do you define bad language?  Words have meaning depending on their context, and software can't determine context.  Ie Is saying that someone likes to eat watermelon something that should be censored?  Well it could be considered racist if applied to certain groups of people.  And that's something your dictionary can't tell.

In the case of images, there is no reliable method to discern nudity via an algorithm.  In fact all websites that do image censoring use humans to categorize and censor user supplied images for that reason (And from what I have read its not the best of jobs to have).  And even the humans make mistakes.  Recently FB rejected an image of a woman In a bath because they mistook her elbow for a naked breast.

Answer (score -1):

Paste this code in your functions.php or custome plugin file

```
///Content Censor code


function censor_content($content) {
    // Array of words to censor
    $censored_words = array('word1', 'word2');

    // Loop through each word to censor
    foreach ($censored_words as $word) {
        // Create a regular expression pattern to match the word
        $pattern = '/\b' . $word . '\b/i';

        // Replace the word with censored version
        $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
            $word = $matches[0];
            $censored_word = substr($word, 0, 2) . str_repeat('*', strlen($word) - 3) . substr($word, -1);
            return $censored_word;
        }, $content);
    }

    // Return the censored content
    return $content;
}

// Add the censor_content function to the WordPress content filter
add_filter('the_content', 'censor_content');
```